# How to Restrict Sales Rep users for not creating the Schedules

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, scheduled

Can any help me out with this?

I have a requirement where i would like to restrict few users Say As **"Sales Rep Users"** for not creating the Schedules .I mean their can create a Opportunity record with the products but should not have the access for scheduling.How can i do this ?

For Example :When a **Sales Rep** is creating a Opportunity record say as **"XYZ"** and opportunity product given as **"ABC"**.Now the Sales Rep should not have the Access to Schedule or Reschedule the products.How can i achieve this.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: and what have you tried?  This looks like you are asking the community to write your code for you.